# Rango de meses entre datepicker

Tags: javascript, php

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente inconveniente tengo dos controles datepicker para establecer fechas desde - hasta, pero no quiero que supere los 6 meses entre ellos enviando un mensaje al usuario que el limite máximo es de 6 meses ....he visto soluciones en javascript pero no me funcionan. Desde ya gracias

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form horizontal">
              <label class="control-label">Fecha desde:</label>
              <input name= "Fechadesde" id="Fechadesde" type="date" class="form-control"  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"  title="Por favor ingrese fecha desde" autofocus required>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form horizontal">
              <label class="control-label">Fecha hasta:</label>
              <input name= "Fechahasta" id="Fechahasta" type="date"  class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" title="Por favor ingrese fecha desde" autofocus required >
            </div>                                            
          </div>
```

Comment: Y que soluciones viste que no funcionaron? a ver si todavia te ponen lo mismo...

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/95436/c%C3%B3mo-crear-rangos-con-jquery-ui-datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo lo intente calculando la cantidad de días espero te funcione

```js
function calcularDiasAusencia(fechaIni, fechaFin) {
  var diaEnMils = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      desde = new Date(fechaIni.substr(0, 10)),
      hasta = new Date(fechaFin.substr(0, 10)),
      diff = hasta.getTime() - desde.getTime() + diaEnMils;// +1 incluir el dia de ini
      return diff / diaEnMils;
}

function validar() {
 var dias= calcularDiasAusencia(
    document.getElementById('Fechadesde').value,
    document.getElementById('Fechahasta').value
  );

  if(dias>=182){//dias aprox en 6 meses
    // lo que necesites hacer 
    console.log("exediste los dias")
    
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form horizontal">
              <label class="control-label">Fecha desde:</label>
              <input name= "Fechadesde" id="Fechadesde" type="date" class="form-control"  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"  title="Por favor ingrese fecha desde" autofocus required onchange="validar()">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form horizontal">
              <label class="control-label">Fecha hasta:</label>
              <input name= "Fechahasta" id="Fechahasta" type="date"  class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" title="Por favor ingrese fecha desde" autofocus required onchange="validar()">
            </div>                                            
          </div>
```

Comment: Excelente ....muchas gracias

Comment: como soluciona el problema? no veo una explicacion de que cambios hiciste o que implementaste o que documentacion utilizaste de referencia...